# SQL query returning null table

Tags: mysql, sql

I recently upsized a database backend to SQL and kept the same frontend, so I'm updating some code, however, I cannot figure out why this returns a null value for .Fields("BuildingID").  Any help would be gladly appreciated!

```
 Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Buildings, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
   .
   .
   .
If Not rst Then
  With rst
   .AddNew
     NewID = .Fields("BuildingID")
```

Comment: I suspect that the "AddNew" has only added a record to the Recordset, it's not yet inserted a row into the database table. I also suspect that BuildingID is declared as an IDENTITY column in SQL Server. I don't think the changes made to a Recordset are applied to the database until you do a .Update on the Recordset.  (The value of the IDENTITY column won't be assigned to the new row before it gets inserted into the SQL Server database.) This isn't an answer, it's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think " should be there like at the end of the select query

```
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Buildings", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

Comment: I think the end of the SELECT query is before the comma following Buildings.  I think what follows the SELECT query are options (e.g. is the set scroll forward only, is it read only, etc.) (This code looks a lot more like the Microsoft stack (e.g. DAO and VB) that it looks like MySQL.